# Tapewound strings on an electric bass

Tags: strings, bass-guitar

Recently tried Veillette and Rob Allen basses, both incredible instruments.  Unfortunately, they're also incredibly expensive.  Part of what I loved was the feel of the tapewound strings.  What would happen if I changed my steel roundwounds on an American Lakland bass to tapewound strings?  In other words, what kind of sound could I expect vs. the two basses I tried?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't actually know you could use these with pickups. Will have to try out a set now.

Comment: Guitarists can use them too! http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/how-do-tape-wound-strings-compare-to-metal-flatwounds

Comment: I put a set of tapewounds on my Jazz Bass in 1973, and every time I take it ot of the case it's rarin' to go. I take it in for routine maintenance, other cats play it, nobody ever asks how old the strings are or have anything negative to say about the sound!

Answer (score 10):

Tapewound strings are similar in construction to other wound bass strings; the difference is that they have a length (or 'tape') of nylon wrapped around a metal core. 
This makes them feel less tough on fingers, and the tone they produce does not quickly degrade in time, as standard round/flatwound strings will.

The Sound they produce is different as well. They deliver a warmer, rounder, softer and smoother tone (because they will produce less string noise). Another word you will hear a lot when describing tapewound strings is 'thump.' For this reason, they are said to produce the closest sound to an upright bass that can be produced on an electric bass.

I have never come into contact with either of these basses, but from a spot of research I understand that they both have a 'semi-hollow' body design and construction. I would presume that this would add a fair amount to the sound, but the strings would also contribute a lot as well.

Replacing your current strings with tapewounds is likely to have a noticeable effect on the sound, but the body construction and the tonewoods that are used are also likely to be a major contributing feature to the bass's tone and sound.

Hope this helps.

*Sources:* [Rob Allen Guitars](http://www.roballenguitars.com/mb2.html) and [Veillette Guitars](http://www.veilletteguitars.com/press_bp_0507.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of instrumentalists confuse tapewounds and flatwounds from roundwounds and other material strings.

Flatwounds are regular roundwounds that are ground-down, in fact, you usually have to wipe off the excess machining from them before installing or else your fingers will blacken.

Tapewounds are correctly described above.

Tapewounds will inherently seem a little "softer" or have less attack since they are wrapped in a material that doesn't fundamentally ring true to the original string.  Flatwounds give you a very similar feel to tapewounds (which feel great for jazz guitar too, BTW) but have a bit more metallic sound to them, and will sustain a bit longer as well, since there is no softer nylon material to deaden vibration.

All bass strings are expensive, especially ones that require extra work aside form the winding.  A good wipe down every once in a while, and after a serious session will extend the life of them as gunk tends to get into the crevasses of the metal windings and corrode.

*But here's some pricing examples of the two:*

[Tapewounds](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/search.jsp?sB=r&Ntt=tapewound+bass+strings) are indeed more labor intensive, but you may be able to find a more affordable set of [flat-wounds](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/search.jsp?sB=r&Ntt=flatwound+bass+strings#N=700008+100502&Ntt=flatwound+bass+strings&sB=r&Nao=0&recsPerPage=40&v=g&Ns=r) which are more comfortable on your fingers and slightly less work to produce, therefore cheaper.